# Run OpenAPI specification as a test on an application that is implementing it

Tags: microservices, openapi, web-api-testing, contract

I am working on developing a way to validate that a Spring Boot web service is adhering to the OpenAPI specification which describes it.

For example, if endpoints that are defined in the OpenAPI specification have not been implemented by the application or if there are mismatches in the request and / or response schema (field names, datatype, etc.), headers, etc. for endpoints that have been implemented, must result in a build failure.

How can I validate this?

Answer (score 2):

What you describe sounds very simple, but it is actually pretty difficult to do. The basic reason for this is that there are so many tests you would have to execute against an API to determine if it aligns with its specification.

However, if you don't require 100% confidence, there are two open source tools which might be worth you looking at:

- Specmatic (https://specmatic.in/documentation/contract_tests.html)
- Dredd (https://dredd.org/en/latest/index.html)

They both work by analyzing the OpenAPI specification and automatically defining test cases which can then be executed against the actual API. This test case generation depends on the specification author (or another party) providing working example requests. Adopting such a tool may therefore require some investment of time, if you don't have examples inline in your specifications.

Comment: CTO of Specmatic here, thanks for the mention. Just wanted to add that Specmatic is also able to give you an API coverage report based on the test execution - https://specmatic.in/updates/detect-mismatches-between-your-api-specifications-and-implementation-specmatic-api-coverage-report/#gsc.tab=0